# Pivot values of field based on another field in TSQL / Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ms-access-2010

Alright here is a table I have with example data. There is a unique key for itemCode and dateType, so no itemCode can have repeating dateType, and vice versa. Also dateStatus is a bit datatype.

```
+----+----------+----------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| id | itemCode | dateType | dateStatus |  dateDue  | dateComplete |
+----+----------+----------+------------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 |      501 | aa       |          1 | 1/1/2014  | 5/1/2014     |
|  2 |      501 | bb       |          0 | 1/2/2014  |              |
|  3 |      501 | cc       |          0 | 1/3/2014  |              |
|  4 |      602 | aa       |          0 | 1/4/2014  |              |
|  5 |      602 | bb       |          1 | 1/5/2014  | 5/5/2014     |
|  6 |      602 | cc       |          0 | 1/6/2014  |              |
|  7 |      602 | dd       |          0 | 1/7/2014  |              |
|  8 |      703 | bb       |          0 | 1/8/2014  |              |
|  9 |      703 | cc       |          0 | 1/9/2014  |              |
| 10 |      703 | dd       |          1 | 1/10/2014 | 5/10/2014    |
+----+----------+----------+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

I'm trying to pivot the dateType against the itemCode and have the value be either dateComplete or dateDue, depending on if the dateStatus is 0 or 1.

```
+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| itemCode |      aa       |      bb       |      cc       |       dd       |
+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
|      501 | fin: 5/1/2014 | due: 1/2/2014 | due: 1/3/2014 |                |
|      602 | due: 1/4/2014 | fin: 5/5/2014 | due: 1/6/2014 | due: 1/7/2014  |
|      703 |               | due: 1/8/2014 | due: 1/9/2014 | fin: 5/10/2014 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
```

I can do this easily in Access Query CrossTab and the SQL results in

```
TRANSFORM First(Switch([dateStatus]=0,"due: " & [dateDue],
                       [dateStatus]=1,"fin: " & [dateComplete])) AS Expr1
SELECT Table1.itemCode
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.itemCode
PIVOT Table1.dateType In ("aa","bb","cc","dd");
```

But I cannot figure out how to build this query in TSQL / Microsoft SQL server management studio. I can get some basic pivots done, but aggregate functions seem to not pull values, so I'm thinking the query may be a combination of pivots, joins and case statements. Or maybe I'm over complicating things.

Any code drop for reference would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: for basic understanding you can see this example: [basic sql pivot query](https://hasanmahmood.com/2019/03/19/basic-pivot-sql-query/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. It's a little simpler than the accepted answer and it's a little more scalable like lets say another dateType is added. All you would have to do is add value in the pivot instead of a whole new case statement.

```
DECLARE @pivotCols VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @pivotCols =  COALESCE(@pivotCols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(dateType)
FROM @yourTable
GROUP BY dateType

EXEC
(
'SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  itemCode,
            CASE 
                WHEN dateStatus = 1 
                    THEN ''fin: '' + CAST(dateComplete AS CHAR(10))
                ELSE ''due: ''  + CAST(dateDue AS CHAR(10))
            END dateDue,
            dateType
    FROM @yourTable
) A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(dateDue) FOR dateType IN (' + @pivotCols + ')
) pvt'
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely as you said more scalable and also very helpful!

Comment: is it possible to stick a select clause with the IN operator? ie. dataType IN (select dateType from dateTypeList). I tried this but get an error. There's maybe something that will work like this? I've got a separate list that controls what dateTypes are available. Thanks

Comment: haha. You can't put a list in directly. Welcome to the bane of SQL. What you're asking for is dynamic SQL. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: yea, I'm starting to come across these limitations in SQL, but I guess they are needed to keep control. Thanks again! The COALESCE worked great.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use conditional aggregation to `pivot` your results, but you also have to use `case` to pick the correct date:

```
select itemcode,
  max(case when dateType = 'aa' and dateStatus = 0 
           then 'due:' + cast(dateDue as varchar(20))
           when dateType = 'aa' and dateStatus = 1
           then 'fin:' + cast(dateComplete as varchar(20))
      end) as aa,
  max(case when dateType = 'bb' and dateStatus = 0 
           then 'due:' + cast(dateDue as varchar(20))
           when dateType = 'bb' and dateStatus = 1
           then 'fin:' + cast(dateComplete as varchar(20))
      end) as bb,
  max(case when dateType = 'cc' and dateStatus = 0 
           then 'due:' + cast(dateDue as varchar(20))
           when dateType = 'cc' and dateStatus = 1
           then 'fin:' + cast(dateComplete as varchar(20))
      end) as cc,
  max(case when dateType = 'dd' and dateStatus = 0 
           then 'due:' + cast(dateDue as varchar(20))
           when dateType = 'dd' and dateStatus = 1
           then 'fin:' + cast(dateComplete as varchar(20))
      end) as dd
from Table1
group by itemCode
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/69d29/2)

Another option is to use the `pivot` command, but you'll still need to use a `case` statement in your subquery to create the correct values with dates.

Comment: This is simply beautiful (not to mention simple!). Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: @thomas -- np, glad it helped.